# Issue with building Newlib

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to crosscompile Newlib library for ARM devices using the arm-none-eabi-XXX from CodeSourcery but i am having some issues. When running ./configure and/or make its showing me messages that arm-none-eabi-cc cannot be found. 
My path is set up correctly. I can call arm-none-eabi-xxx from terminal as root and as user.

The command:

```
sudo ./configure --target=arm-none-eabi  --prefix=/usr/local/arm-eabi/bin --disable-newlib-supplied-syscalls
```

Result:

```
checking for arm-none-eabi-cc... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-gcc... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-c++... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-g++... no


sudo make:
/bin/sh: arm-none-eabi-cc: command not found
```

But path set up correctly...

```
kris@caspinol /usr/local/newlib $ arm
arm2hpdl                 arm-none-eabi-c++        arm-none-eabi-elfedit    arm-none-eabi-gcov       arm-none-eabi-ld         arm-none-eabi-ranlib     arm-none-eabi-sprite     
arm-none-eabi-addr2line  arm-none-eabi-cc         arm-none-eabi-g++        arm-none-eabi-gdb        arm-none-eabi-nm         arm-none-eabi-readelf    arm-none-eabi-strings    
arm-none-eabi-ar         arm-none-eabi-c++filt    arm-none-eabi-gcc        arm-none-eabi-gdbtui     arm-none-eabi-objcopy    arm-none-eabi-run        arm-none-eabi-strip      
arm-none-eabi-as         arm-none-eabi-cpp        arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.6.3  arm-none-eabi-gprof      arm-none-eabi-objdump    arm-none-eabi-size       
kris@caspinol /usr/local/newlib $ arm
```

Am I missing some arguments during configure stage??

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `sudo`. It looks like it's changing your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Actually, lets forget about `PATH` and the error, for a moment. Why *are* you doing this with `sudo`? Never become `root` unless necessary.

Comment: Thats it, sudo was the issue. Thanks guys.